# No recipients found in nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I am trying to send a mail using nodemailer.
I think i have given all the mailOptions correctly. As i have confirmed that by printing mailOptions to the console.

And i have also checked auth and user. They are correct and well imported.

But still i am getting no recipient defined error. Where is the problem?

[image]

Here is the entire sendEmail function

```
function sendEmail(payload) {
var fromEmail = config.cfg.smtp.fromEmail;

console.log(fromEmail);
var toEmail = payload.to;
var subject = payload.subject;
var content = `<p>Greetings! your order is on the way. Order details are</p>`;
let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",

  auth: {
    user: config.cfg.smtp.auth.user,
    pass: config.cfg.smtp.auth.pass,
  },
});
// setup email data with unicode symbols
let mailOptions = {
  from: fromEmail, // sender address.  Must be the same as authenticated user if using Gmail.
  to: toEmail, // receiver
  subject: subject, // subject
  html: content, // html body
};

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  smtpTransport.sendMail({ mailOptions }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(mailOptions)

    if (err) {
      console.log("your mail could not be sent");
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(data);
    console.log("Your mail is sent");
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending your `mailOptions` inside another object. Try the following instead.

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) { // mailOptions is already an object.
    console.log(mailOptions)

    if (err) {
      console.log("your mail could not be sent");
      return reject(err);
    }
    resolve(data);
    console.log("Your mail is sent");
  });
```